# Identifying an optics equation in a code refactoring project

Tags: optics, models, vision

I apologise if this a somewhat naive post. My knowledge of optics is limited, and I am learning on the job, so to speak. I'm a computational biologist, dabbling in a bit of physics. I'm currently reading Sonke Johnsen's "The Optics of Life" to try and get a better picture.

I am involved in an academic project to refactor some obsolete code from a program created over 15 years ago, which models the resolution and sensitivity in reflective superposition compound eyes. The problem is that a lot of the code uses non-descriptive variables that are difficult for me to interpret.

I am stuck with working out what this is doing:

```
DA = sqrt((ER * ER) - (AR * AR))    /* DA??? */
AC = atan(AR / DA) / CONV           /* AC??? */
```

This is then used to adjust the aperture diameter:

```
AD = (AC / 360.0) * EC              /* adjust aperture diameter */
```

In this code the variables definitions are as follows:

> ER = eye radius
>
> AR = aperture radius
>
> CONV = pi / 180.0 (converts radians to degrees)
>
> AD = aperture diameter
>
> EC = eye circumference

What might `DA` and `AC` be? Any help should be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Hi Steve, I suspect much more code and context about how DA and AC are used will be needed.  Unfortunately reverse-engineering code is off topic here.

Comment: Hi Brandon. Those three lines are the only place it is used. I need to be able to understand the model fully in order to implement the code effectively. Its as much a question about the optics, therefore, as it is in helping me to implement a programmatic solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I think the first bit of the calculation does. Suppose you start with a spherical eye with a hole in it (e.g. the pupil in the human eye):

[image: Eye1]

The radius of the eye is $ER$ and the radius of the hole is $AR$, and with the length $DA$ these form a right angled triangle. Pythagoras' theorem tells us:

$$ DA^2 + AR^2 = ER^2 $$

so:

$$ DA = \sqrt{ER^2 - AR^2} $$

which is what your first line of code calculates. So $DA$ is the distance from the centre of the eye to the centre of the hole. The angle $AC$ is then given by:

$$ \tan AC = \frac{AR}{DA} $$

so:

$$ AC = \arctan \left( \frac{AR}{DA} \right) $$

which is what the second line of code calculates. If you now put a cornea over the hole to make the eye spherical again:

[image: Eye2]

Then the length of the arc $AD$ is simply:

$$ AD = EC \frac{AC}{2\pi} $$

which is what your third line calculates, although there's something a bit odd here as if $AD$ stands for *Aperture Diameter* then there is a factor of two missing.

Comment: For my next trick I will guess your birthday and inside leg measurement :-)

Comment: Isn't $2\pi=360$? Or am I misunderstanding the factor of 2 difference?

Comment: Fantastic John, thank you! I'm guessing DA must have meant distance to aperture in that case. Need to scrub up on my maths I think :S

Comment: Quick typo I noticed... $$DA^2+AT^2=ER^2$$ should be $$DA^2+AR^2=ER^2$$

Comment: @SteveMoss: oops, yes, well spotted!

Comment: @SteveMoss: scrubbing up on math is always good. But I think the real lesson you should be learning here is to use meaningful variable names and _document your code_ ;)

Comment: @chase: I doubt Steve needs the lesson. Some years ago I was put in the same position as Steve i.e. having to update several thousand lines of QBasic with one or two letter variable names, no comments, and the person who wrote had long since left. I still have occasional nightmares about it :-) Just to add to the stress it was a program for calculating equilibria in solution, and it was used by the nuclear industry to check the stuff swilling around in their cooling pipes wasn't going to corrode through the pipes and give the local groundwater that pretty blue glow.

Comment: Thanks chase. I'm certainly well versed in software engineering best practices. I need to understand the system as well as the code however, so I can visualise the problem in my head. One lesson I've learnt from this is to get things out of my head and onto paper... if I had drawn things out like this, it would have been much easier to understand :)